# php api doesnt send any message to react native app

Tags: php, react-native

I am writing a react native code in which I post some values to PHP API by "Axios fetch function", and I don't get any response . and my PHP code is correct because I tested it in the browser
here is my code: it should return some message(an array with message) whether success or fail but in the react native app the message is undefined when I alert it.
react native code(It's a function called by a button and the state has a default value and is never null):

```
 sendRating(){
    axios.post("http://192.168.1.107/restaurant/setRate.php", {
        rating: this.state.Default_Rating,
        ID:this.state.restId
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.data.message == "success"){
            
            alert("امتیاز شما ثبت شد");
            
        }
        else if(response.data.message == "failure"){
            alert("لطفا بعدا دوباره تلاش کنید");
        }  
        else{
            alert(response.data.message);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my setRate.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once "config.php";
   $json=file_get_contents("php://input");
   $json = json_decode($json , true);
   $Id = $json['ID'];
   $rating=$json['rating'];
   $sqlQuery="SELECT  `rate` , `id` FROM restaurants WHERE `id`=".$Id;
   $result=$conn->query($sqlQuery);

   if($result->num_rows==1){
       $temp=$result->fetch_assoc();
       $tempVote=$temp['votes']+1;
       $tempRate=(($temp['rate']*$temp['votes'])+$rating)/$tempVote;

       $change_rate_query = "UPDATE `restaurants` SET `rate`='$tempRate', `votes`='$tempVote'      WHERE `id` = '$Id'";
       If ($conn->query($change_rate_query))
           $data=array('message' =>"success" );     
   }
   else{
       $data=array('message' =>"failure" );
   }
   echo json_encode($data);
   $conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: Did you have some PHP error in your logs ? because it can failed after your update and never set the $data variable

Comment: Try to echo SQL error to can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing parsing `response.data` as `json` in your react-native code.
Convert the raw data you received to json using `JSON.parse(response.data)`.

So you could replace your `sendRating` method with this:

```
function sendRating() {
  axios
    .post("http://192.168.1.107/restaurant/setRate.php", {
      rating: this.state.Default_Rating,
      ID: this.state.restId,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      var jsonResponseData = JSON.parse(response.data);
      if (jsonResponseData.message == "success") {
        alert("امتیاز شما ثبت شد");
      } else if (jsonResponseData.message == "failure") {
        alert("لطفا بعدا دوباره تلاش کنید");
      } else {
        alert(jsonResponseData.message);
      }
    });
}
```

Note: Make sure that the response is not null and also that the data is a valid json before parsing.